# How to remove points based on their attributes in Houdini?

Tags: houdini, vex

I created a curve with several points. Now I want to delete some points based on one of their attribute (will_be_removed).

[image: geometry spreadsheet]

As is shown in the picture above, those points with `i@will_be_removed` set to 1 will be removed.

I tried using the VEX code below but it said invalid subscript for type: int.will_be_removed

```
if(@ptnum.will_be_removed == 1)
{
    removepoint(0, @ptnum);
}
```

How can I correctly reference those points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figure out a way to do it. Use @will_be_removed instead of @ptnum.will_be_removed instead:

```
if(@will_be_removed == 1)
{
    removepoint(0, @ptnum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error in this code

```
if(@ptnum.will_be_removed == 1)
{
    removepoint(0, @ptnum);
}
```

is because `@ptnum` is a [VEX type int](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/vex/snippets#known). `@ptnum` can also be written `i@ptnum` to exlicitly indicate it's type, but since it is a well known attribute (see documentation in link) you can also write it shorthand as `@ptnum`.

`int` types are numbers, and do not contain collections of other data.

Regarding attributes, you also want to keep in mind if they are [vertex, point, primitive, or detail attributes](https://www.sidefx.com/docs/houdini/model/attributes).

> ### Attribute precedence
>
> When two components in the same geometry have an attribute with the same name, the
>   attribute on the "lower level" of geometry is used, so:
>
> Vertex attributes, which override:
>
> Point attributes, which override:
>
> Primitive attributes, which override:
>
> Detail (whole geometry) attributes

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

or one liner wrangler will be

```
if (@will_be_deleted == 1) removepoint(0, @ptnum);
```